# Card (must be enchantment or artifact) that allows multiple of the same legend in play at once?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I think its an older card. I've been googling for about a half and hour and cant find it.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The OP is clearly looking for Mirror Gallery, and the linked question is explicitly *not* looking for Mirror Gallery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The card you're thinking of is [Mirror Gallery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirror%20Gallery%5d) from Betrayers of Kamigawa. You probably couldn't find it because the wording on the card is a little odd:

> The "legend rule" doesn't apply.